# moving from PL/JSON to JSON_VALUE

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c, pljson

We've upgraded our database to Oracle 12 and I'd like to move from PL/JSON to The in built JSON parsing tool. Has anyone done this and have you been successful?

The issue I'm currently have is that json_value will only accept 4000 characters max - anything over this it will not parse.

Has anyone come across this issue and discovered a fix.

Has anyone a link to a decent tutorial on JSON_QUERY and JSON_VALUE. The Oracle documentation can be a little dense

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`JSON_` functions work easily with CLOB datatypes so you can process much bigger JSONs than 4000 B but the limit for returned value is VARCHAR2 limit which is 4/32k depending on database settings and I don't think you can do anything about within SQL.